# SSL certificate for subdomain without domain

Tags: ssl, https, subdomain, certificate

I have a webserver in my intranet which can be accessed via `subdomain.domain.com` *and* simply `subdomain`. The SSL certificate is created for `subdomain.domain.com` which results in a warning as soon as I access just `subdomain` via https.

Any idea how this can be solved? (yes, I don't know much about ssl server configuration :-)

Comment: How are you signing the certificates?

Comment: selfsigned - don't ask about the details...

Comment: Look for Server Name Indication (SNI) or Subject Alternate Name (SAN) capability in your signing or request generation.  You should be able to just submit `subdomain` as an alternative. Note that there might be some browser incompatibility with those methods, particularly with older browsers.

Comment: hm. It seems sthat there is a problem with SNI and IE on XP...

Comment: Yes.  IE on XP would be an issue.  Hmm.  It's an intranet.  Do you control IP allocation?  If so, and you're supporting browsers that don't play well with SNI, you might just set up a second IP address on that machine, and deal with it the old fashioned way: one cert per IP address.  The `subdomain` virtual host can just do a redirect to `subdomain.domain.com`.  If you can do SAN, you might have broader compatibility: http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add the alternate names to the certificate when signing. For example, if you use OpenSSL and you use the `server_ca` section when signing (e.g. `openssl ca -config my.conf -name server_ca -in server.req -out server.crt`) , make sure you have a section similar to the following in the config file you use when signing:

```
[server_ca]
...
x509_extensions = server_cert

[server_cert]
...
subjectAltName = @server_alt_names

[server_alt_names]
DNS.1 = subdomain.domain.com
DNS.2 = subdomain
```

To verify your certificate, pipe it to `openssl x509 -noout -text`. You should see a line like this in the output:

```
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:subdomain.domain.com, DNS:subdomain
```

I saw the comment about SNI but if you just sign the certificate SNI will not matter at all (as long as both names are supposed to point to the same content). This method works for sure for Firefox and IE, not at all for Chrome and wget. In fact, the CN in the certificate does not even matter if you have the names listed as alternate names.